# Microsoft Graph: How to add new line in your message while sending reply mail?

Tags: node.js, microsoft-graph-api

Using this api https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-reply?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http I'm sending a reply mail to users by passing this in the body.

```
msg = "This is line 1.\nThis is line 2.\nThis is line 3."
var data = JSON.stringify({
    "message": {
      "toRecipients": [
        {
          "emailAddress": {
            "address": address,
            "name": name
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "comment": msg
  });
```

When a user gets an email, the message looks like this:

```
This is line1.This is line2.This is line3
```

instead of this output:

```
This is line1.
This is line2.
This is line3.
```

Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: It should respect the body content type of the original message. If content type is html then <br> should work, otherwise \n\n or \n\r

Comment: @user2250152 I even tried \n\n, \r\n\n didn't work. I don't know if using html content type will able to add new line I haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 1):

Using comment property the api doesn't add new line.
Instead of using comment, using body property will allow adding new lines

```
msg = "This is line 1.\nThis is line 2.\nThis is line 3."
var data = JSON.stringify({
    "message": {
      "body": {
          "contentType": "Text",
          "content": msg
      },
      "toRecipients": [
        {
          "emailAddress": {
            "address": address,
            "name": name
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  });
```

output:

```
This is line1.
This is line2.
This is line3.
```